# SCP from Remote Server Problems

Tags: debian, ssh, scp

I have a really old Debian remote Server.

Unfortunately the APT is broken so I cant update or install anything. The last thing before I delete the Server is download some files and folders.

I know I can do it with SCP but because the Server is so old I cant connect with ssh in one step.

I have to do that command to get into the server:

> ssh -oKexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -c aes128-cbc
> root@000.000.000.000.

The problem is when I want to download something with SCP it stops because of the missing encryption and ciphers.

Debian Version: Debian GNU/Linux 3.1

Comment: Why can't you use the same connection options and cipher for scp as you do for ssh?

Comment: Because I dont know how to integrate it into the SCP command. How would it look like?

Comment: Exactly the same. I've added you an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the same SSH options to `scp` as you can pass to `ssh`:

```
scp -r -oKexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -c aes128-cbc root@000.000.000.000:/ /home/freddy/backup
```

Alternatively, the good' ole "pipe a `tar` archive through SSH" still works - without `scp`, and especially on old `scp` implementations with less well-designed buffer management/queuing might me much faster.

```
ssh -oKexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 \
    -c aes128-cbc \
    root@000.000.000.000 \
    tar -cfz - folder/to/be/sent \
    | \
    tar -xzf -
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I dont know why it didnt work for me as I tried to implement the encryption and ciphers. I bet I mistyped all the time.

Comment: "_I bet I mistyped all the time_" you can set these as preferences in your `~/.ssh/config` for the target host. See `man ssh_config` for details, or search here on [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can use exactly the same options for `scp` as you can for `ssh`

```
scp -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -c aes128-cbc root@000.000.000.000.  remoteUser@remoteHost:/path/to/files… /local/path/to/files
```

See `man scp` for the details; here's the summary:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> scp [-346BCpqrTv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] source ... target